# cannot read property 'join' of undefined - React

Tags: javascript, react

Estou recebendo esse problema quando tento submeter um formulário com react no front e node no backend.
Esse formulário cadastra uma loja. Ao clicar em salvar, era para ele pegar as categorias da loja e garantir que elas estejam agrupadas (join) com uma "," e um espaço entre elas:

```
 <span>{shop.shopCategories.join(', ')}</span>
```

O código completo da onde ocorre o erro está abaixo:

```
import React from 'react';

import './style.css';

function ShopItem({shop}) {
  return (
    <li className="shop-item">
      <header>
        <img src='https://jornalggn.com.br/sites/default/files/u16/imagem-sem-foto-de-perfil-do-facebook-1348864936180_956x5001.jpg' alt= {shop.shopFantasyName} /> 
          <div className= "shop-info">
            <strong>{shop.shopName}</strong>
            <span>{shop.shopCategories.join(', ')}</span>   // ESSA É A LINHA APONTADA NO ERRO //
          </div>
      </header>
  <p>sobre a loja</p>
  <a href= "http://www.google.com"> Acessar todos os produtos de {shop.shopFantasyName}</a>
  </li>
  )
}

export default ShopItem;
```

O estranho é que depois quando recarrego a página, a loja fica salva no banco e é mostrada na página das lojas cadastradas, ou seja, esse erro não impede de cadastrar a loja.

Essa é minha rota post:

```
    async store(req, res) {
        const {shopName, shopEmail, shopCNPJ, shopFantasyName, shopPhoneNumber, shopCategories, latitude, longitude} = req.body;

        let shop = await Shop.findOne({shopCNPJ});

        if(!shop) {

            const shopCategoriesArray = parseStringAsArray(shopCategories);

            const shopLocation = {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [longitude, latitude],
            };

            shop = await Shop.create({

                shopLocation,
                shopCategories: shopCategoriesArray,
                shopName,
                shopEmail,
                shopCNPJ,
                shopFantasyName,
                shopPhoneNumber,


            })
            console.log(shopCategoriesArray);
        }

      return res.json({shop:[]});
    }
};
```

E esse é o controler:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import api from './services/api';

import './global.css';
import './App.css';
import './Sidebar.css';
import './Main.css';

import ShopItem from './components/ShopItem';
import ShopForm from './components/ShopForm';

function App() {

  const [shops, setShops] = useState([]);

  
  useEffect(()=>{  
    async function loadShops() {
      const res = await api.get('/shops');

      setShops(res.data);
    }
    loadShops();
  }, []);

  
  async function handleAddShop(data) {
    const res = await api.post('/shops', data)
    
  setShops([...shops, res.data])
}

  
    
  return (
    <div id="app">
      <header >
        <head> 
          <p>
            teste
          </p>
        </head>
      </header>
      <aside>
          <strong> Cadastre sua empresa</strong>
          <ShopForm onSubmit={handleAddShop}/>
      </aside>
      <main>
        <ul>
          {shops.map(shop => (
             <ShopItem key={shop._id}  shop={shop}/>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </main>
      <footer>

      </footer>
    </div>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Não sei mais o que fazer!! Alguém me dá um help, toda vez que salvo uma loja o erro ocorre!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo menos no trecho de código postado, na sua rota para `POST /shops`, parece que você está fazendo:

```js
return res.json({ shop: [] });
```

Ou seja, ao final da inserção da nova loja, você simplesmente envia como resposta um objeto que possui um campo chamado `shop`, que porta uma *array* vazia.

Se essa rota corresponde a:

```js
await api.post('/shops', data)
```

Então, pode-se dizer que você está pegando esse objeto e misturando com as outras lojas. Ou seja:

```js
setShops( [ ...shops, res.data ] );
// seria o mesmo que:
// setShops( [ ...shops, { shop: [] } ] );
```

Assim, quando você faz:

```js
shops.map( shop => ( ... ) )
```

Chegará um ponto onde `shop` corresponderá ao `{ shop: [] }`.

Consequentemente, quando você faz `shop.shopCategories` (e acho que não só esse campo, mas, se assim for, com todos os outros isso também acontece), retorna `undefined`. Então, isso:

```html
<span>{shop.shopCategories.join(', ')}</span>
```

Se torna o mesmo que:

```html
<span>{(undefined).join(', ')}</span>
```

O que causa o erro.

---

Desse modo, uma forma de resolver isso seria realizar a requisição `POST` somente para *cadastrar* as lojas, e então usaria a função `loadShops` para *carregar* as lojas:

```js
async function loadShops() {
  const res = await api.get('/shops');

  setShops(res.data);
}

useEffect(loadShops, []);

async function handleAddShop(data) {
    const res = await api.post('/shops', data);
        
    await loadShops();
}
```

O que até deixaria as coisas melhor separadas, ou seja: `handleAddShop` faz a **inserção** de uma *nova loja*; e `loadShops` **carrega** a *lista de lojas*. Porém, essa alternativa poderia trazer alguma alteração no desempenho e no tempo de resposta da aplicação, já que iria consistir numa atualização (talvez) desnecessária das outras lojas.

Portanto, uma outra alternativa é simplesmente substituir o objeto `{ shop: [] }` pela própria variável `shop`, a qual irá consistir na última loja adicionada:

```js
return res.json(shop);
```

Porém, lembre-se que: se não entrar no

```js
if (!shop) {
```

Significará que a loja já existe na base de dados. E se já existe, então o usuário que tentou adicionar deve tomar conhecimento disto, para exatamente evitar a existência de dados duplicados, podendo até sugerir um possível caminho para a atualização daquela loja, ao invés de reinserção da mesma — funcionalidade, inclusive, que, se já não houver, você poderia criar (claro, novamente digo, se for de sua preferência).

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Eu estava com esse problema há algum tempo, tudo que eu fiz foi transformar isso: ```return res.json({ shop: [] });``` nisso: ```return res.json(shop);```  Não alterei nada no front, somente na rota! Muito obrigado pois foi através da sua ajuda que percebi onde estava o problema!